# How can I share code between Laravel Dusk Browser tests, unit tests, and functional tests

Tags: laravel-dusk, laravel-testing

Unit tests created with `php artisan make:test -- unit UnitTestClassName` extends `\Tests\TestCase`

Functional Tests create with `php artisan make:test FunctionalTestClassName` also extends `\Tests\TestCase`

`\Tests\TestCase` extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`

However, Laravel Dusk browser test case create with `php artisan dusk:make DuskTestClassName` extend `\Tests\DuskTestCase`, which in turn extends `Laravel\Dusk\TestCase`

There appears to be no common class to which I can add things like which user to test with (at least outside of the vendor folder).

To allow shared code, I have created a trait in app\Traits\TestData.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Traits;
trait TestData {
  static $testUserId = 40;
  public static function checkTestData() {
    // returns an array of strings describing any problems with the test data setup.
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

and I `use` that trait in my tests. Is there any better way? Specifically, is there a common testing class I am missing?

The specific issue I am having is that my trait does not extend any TestCase, so I can't call functions like

`$this->assertNotNull($testUser,"Test user not found");`

in my trait, so I need to duplicate that code in the TestCase and DuskTestCase.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the assert methods statically in the trait:

```
self::assertNotNull($testUser,"Test user not found");
```